# Easiest Fetch request for getting just the 'latest' Single entity - core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a Parent `<-->>` Child relationship (to-many).
And the relationship is when i need to fetch all child(s), `Parent.children = (NSSet *) child(s)`

There are times when I just need only **one, latest** entity based on a timeStamp attribute of the Child entity.

I was wandering what would be the easiest way to fetch it, easier than say creating a fetch request and setting fetch limit One and using a sort descriptor to order it based on timeStamp.

Is there an easier way? just calling maybe :

```
[Parent.children firstObject];
```

The reason is I'm gonna need to fetch it many times, through out the life of the app. In some cases, i though i'd have to fetch the latest Child entity in the `-(void)awakeFromFetch() of a Parent Entity`.. and thats why i wanted to have a way thats more easier than anything else specially in terms of memory.

---

When Fetching Child entities, i kinda fetch a  bunch of them that are child to 2 or more Parent entities using this predicate :

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"forParent IN %@", [Array of Parents]];
```

From the resultant NSSet, since i'd get all the required Child entities for the said object,  it would be very convenient if  I could allot a pointer to a **latest child** in according to its **timeStamp** attribute (NSDate).

Obviously after I'd get the NSSet result i could iterate over each child and allot a pointer to the latest entity i find in the NSSet, but it looks pretty painstaking, though i'd have to allot just one pointer to the latest entity of a particular **Parent** , iterating an NSSet which potentially could have more than a hundred  entities seems `bad programming`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of limit 1 and sort, I've used for similiar problem NSExpression with `max:` function. Other solution is to create in model on parent entity a latestChild property and set it when creating every new child. It's not ideal, but works and it's fastest solution.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit man? i didn't quite get 'creating in model on parent entity'

Comment: Let me explain :) you have two entities - Parent and Child. Add new property named latestChild to Parent entity in your model (MOM defined by xcode) and set this latestChild to child recently added to Parent.childrens. So, finally latestChild is direct relation to Child instead of calculated relation through predicates or iterations.

Comment: ups… not MOM but xcdatamodel :)

Comment: @thom_ek i did exactly that :) Instead of a property, I added another One-on-One relationship between Parent and Child, called it latestChild, in any case, i do have to iterate throw other child entities, and if i reach the last index count of the array, i just add it to the single latestChild relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.  The fetch request, with fetchLimit = 1, sorted by time is actually not a bad option.  You can even make the timestamp field an INDEX in the model GUI, and the lookup will be super fast.

If the database will be constantly changing, and you always want access to the most recent item, consider registering for the DidSave notification on the NSManagedObjectContext.

You can get called when the context is saved (or even when there are changes to any object).  In the notification method, just look at the inserted items, and update to take the most recent value.

You can search the inserted objects, and grab the matching entity with the biggest timestamp.

The notifications for save and object change are:

NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification